# Cycles = 0 in Lost-grid

Tags: css, stylus

I don't understand the logic behind `cycle` [in the given example](https://github.com/corysimmons/lost#controlling-cycle), where it talks about `.quarter`, `.half` classes.

I understand using `1` as cycle means *set margin-right: 0 after element n. 1, then carriage-return*.

What does `0` stand for, and what it does?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 0 is a default. You only change the 0 to something else if you want `margin-right: 0;` applied to any item before the last one in a row.

The example uses this as a confusing example:

```
div {
  lost-column: 2/4 2;
}
```

This assumes that you have 4 items in a row. But the math tells you that this is actually 1/2, meaning that your four items are going to be 50% each. Thus every 2nd item in this row will need `margin-right: 0;` to fit correctly.

In this case you'd probably just want to do this if you have four items in a row:

```
div {
  lost-column: 1/2;
}
```

...when in Rome...

Stay awesome!

Comment: Cycle is totally explained in this video by Level Up tuts http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/postcss-tutorials/8-basic-lost-grid